# PowerShell v2.0 equivalent to "get-job | receive-job -AutoRemoveJob -Wait"?

Tags: powershell, jobs

What is the PowerShell v2.0 equivalent to this v3.0 code snippt:

```
for($i=0; $i -lt $num_jobs; $i++) {
    Write-Host -ForegroundColor Darkgreen "[i] Job" $i "starting..."
    Start-Job -ScriptBlock $insert_data -ArgumentList 'host', 'user', 'pass', 'db', $i, $log_out[$i] | Out-Null;
}

get-job | receive-job -AutoRemoveJob -Wait
```

I tried the following without luck

```
for($i=0; $i -lt $num_jobs; $i++) {
    Write-Host -ForegroundColor Darkgreen "[i] Job" $i "starting..."
    Start-Job -ScriptBlock $insert_data -ArgumentList 'host', 'user', 'pass', 'db', $i, $log_out[$i] | Out-Null;
}

get-job | receive-job -Wait 
get-job | remove-job
```

It fails on PowerShell v2.0 with:

```
Remove-Job : The command cannot remove the job with the 3 session identifier be
cause the job is not finished. To remove the job, first stop the job, or use th
e Force parameter.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best I can come up with for V2 is:

```
Get-Job | % {while ($_.HasMoreData) { Receive-Job $_; Sleep 1 }; Remove-Job $_}
```

Note: I recommend using the Get-Job -Id parameter in the event you have more than one job running. Also, a 1 second sleep might be a bit long, you could tweak that to say 250 millisecs.

For multiple jobs, you could do this:

```
while ($jobs = Get-Job) { $jobs | %{if ($_.HasMoreData) {Receive-Job $_} else {Remove-Job $_}}; Sleep 1};
```

Comment: Nice approach. But it only returns the output for one specific job. If i am running e.g. 8 jobs in parallel and i remove '-id x' only the first jobs is shown... any workaround for this?

Answer (score 0):

try this in two distinct lines:

```
get-job | wait-job | receive-job
get-job | remove-job
```

Comment: Thanks for replying. If i try it your way it works... but i am only able to receive output from my task when it actually has finished and not when it acutally starts...